# Placing Toolbar Button in Specific Position by Firefox Add-on SDK

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I can add a Toolbar Button by this code

```
var { ActionButton } = require("sdk/ui/button/action");

var button = ActionButton({
    id: "addon-button",
    label: "Addon",
    icon: {
      "16": "./icon-16.png",
      "32": "./icon-32.png"
    },
    onClick: function(state) {
        //foo
    }
})
```

But the button is placed at the end of toolbar.

How can I add the button next to Home button? Is it possible to set a specific position for Add-on SDK buttons?

Comment: I don't think you can do it with the SDK. You will have to use CustomizableUI.jsm - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/CustomizableUI.jsm#Comprehensive_Example

Comment: Thanks @Noitidart.  I will try Customizable library.